# How to Correctly Apply Abel's Summation Formula for an Infinite Sum?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

To solve the following sum using Abel's summation formula, I have

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{2^{n-1}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}x\left(2-2^{1-x}\right)-\int_{1}^{\infty}\left(2-2^{1-t}\right)dt$

However, this yields $x\left(2-2^{1-x}\right)-\left(\left(2x+\frac{2^{1-x}}{\ln\left(2\right)}\right)-\left(2+\frac{1}{\ln\left(2\right)}\right)\right)=-2^{-x+1}x-\frac{2^{-x+1}-1}{\ln \left(2\right)}+2$. When taking the limit to infinity, I get $\frac{1}{\ln \left(2\right)}+2$ instead of $4$ (this approach underestimates the sum's convergence). I must be applying the formula incorrectly, so I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: $$\sum_{n \leqslant t} \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} = 2^{1 - \lfloor t\rfloor}$$ and not $2^{1-t}$.

Comment: Thank you for response. When dealing with infinities, the limit of both $2^{1-\lfloor t\rfloor}$ and $2^{1-t}$ is $0$. The integral for either case is also asymptotically equivalent. I may be wrong or another approach is required. In such a case, I would be happy to hear your thoughts.

Comment: The integrals are strictly positive, finite, and different. Therefore they are not asymptotically equivalent. And that is where your error lies, $$\frac{1}{\log 2} = \int_1^{\infty} 2^{1-t}\,dt < \int_1^{\infty} 2^{1 - \lfloor t\rfloor}\,dt = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} 2^{1-k} = 2\,.$$

Comment: Yes, you are exactly right. I was confusing the integral's equivalence to summation (such that $\int_{1}^{\infty}2-2^{1-\lfloor u\rfloor}du=\left[2u\right]_{1}^{\infty}-\sum_{u=1}^{\infty}2^{1-u}$) with both integrals (with and without floor function) being equivalent. This works perfectly, thank you so much.